# Junk Character Display In Google Chart

Tags: html, jsp, google-visualization

I am using Google Chart for the Draw Chart.
But in this Google Chart some language is not supported like as a French, Arabic, etc.

Google chart display like  " S�lectionn� "

so please tell me how can i solve it.

```
data.addColumn('number', 'Sélectionné');
data.addColumn('number', 'Relié');
```

Comment: Your code is not encoded in UTF-8. That simple.

Comment: But in the HTML page it is working. but only in google chart not working.

Comment: Give Your mail so i will send to you code and snapshot of google chart with junk character.

Comment: From your question it is not clear if you have `<meta charset="UTF-8">` in `head` section. If you don't, then that is the solution. See [example at jsbin](http://jsbin.com/nuhoyu/1/edit).